# GCE Boot fail with disk from snapshot

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, google-compute-engine, boot

i try in GCE to create a copy of a running system, i did a snapshot from the running system and set up a new instance. On starting it showed to be running but the log from console one says:

```
    SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-google)
    
    Total RAM Size = 0x0000000100000000 = 4096 MiB
    
    CPUs found: 2     Max CPUs supported: 2
    
    found virtio-scsi at 0:3
    
    virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
    
    virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520 = 10240 MiB
    
    drive 0x000f22f0: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520
    
    Sending Seabios boot VM event.
    
    Booting from Hard Disk 0...
```

So the system is not reachable. I Tryed to check the UUID of the drive but it seems to be the right one. Can someone tell me how to fix this.

Best regards
Alex

Comment: Try creating another VM from the same snapshot and boot it. Then please update your question with the serial console output - this will be a start for any troubleshooting.

Comment: I tryed it multiple times and this what you see in my message is the export of the serial console port 1. Always the same result. Port 2-4 are empty.

Comment: Is that the entire serial console output you get from this VM ? Try using `gcloud` utility for that: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/viewing-serial-port-output#viewing_serial_port_output and paste the results here.

Comment: If possible please provide the info about: OS, machine type, region/zone, if there enough free disk space on the original VM, commands/outputs while creating a snapshot.

Comment: Ok, i checked again, and with all other instances i can create new ones from the snapshots. The log output with the gcloud tool is the same as the output on gcloud console. the orgiginal instance is located in europe-west3-a, it is a debian stable (as on all the other instances).

Comment: Do you have enough free space on the VM's system disk in question ? Check it with `df -h` - if not - resize the system disk.

Comment: The disk of the vm is 10gb, used is 6 gb and the snapshot is allso around 6gb. i thint this should be ok?

Comment: Do you have any older snapshots of this VM ? Try using one of those.

Comment: No, they are all gone, i normaly keep them only 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

What you're experiencing looks very much like a bug. You may try to stop the VM, take a snapshot and try creating new one.

My recommendation would be to contact [GCP support](https://cloud.google.com/support) to get more immediate help (however it's a paid service) or open up a new issue at [Google IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) to get help for free but there are not ETA's for this.